# MongoDB query for a specific field for each document?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have 2 users in my user collection:

```
id: "1",
outer: {
    field1: {
        inner1: {
            a: cats
            b: car
        }
    }
}

id: "2",
outer: {
    field1: {
        inner1: {
            a: dogs
            b: bus
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say I have 10 users. I want to get the value of field "a" for every user in my database. How do I make this query (in mongo shell)?

Comment: I think you have to use the aggregate functions to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
db.user.find({'field1.a': { $exists: true }, { 'field1.a': 1 });
```

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments, you can also just do a `project` using the aggregation framework.

```
db.user.aggregate({ $project: { a: '$field1.inner1.a' } });
```

Comment: Do you think it is going to work because field1 is nested sub document of the user1 document .

Comment: so, `user1` and `user2` are both embedded documents, not their own top level document?

Comment: I guess so... but @yimmy can confirm.

Comment: Yes! field1 is nested in user1/user2, and a is nested in field1

Comment: Sorry guys! I just realized my situation was that there is even one more nested thing. I edited it the object above

Comment: @yimmy - edited to show a `project` - this still assumes that `user` and `user2` are separate documents...

Comment: I edited it again to try to be more clear. I'm showing user 1 and user 2, they are both part of the same user collection. Let's say there are even more though. I want to query to get a list of all the values for the field "a"

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how nested the objects get, just use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation). I wrote out an example below. Your documents were incomplete and ill-formed in a bunch of different ways, so I took the liberty of completing them while trying to match what I think you meant for them to look like.

```
> db.nested.insert([
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "outer" : {
        "field1" : {
            "inner1" : {
                "a" : "cats",
                "b" : "car"
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "outer" : {
        "field1" : {
            "inner1" : {
                "a" : "dogs",
                "b" : "bus"
            }
        }
    }
}])
> db.nested.find({}, { "_id" : 0, "outer.field1.inner1.a" : 1 })
{ "outer" : { "field1" : { "inner1" : { "a" : "cats" } } } }
{ "outer" : { "field1" : { "inner1" : { "a" : "dogs" } } } }
```

Selecting a subset of the fields of a document is called [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/).